# Ruby on Rails - need to add a sticky footer with scroll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, footer

I really need some help getting a sticky footer with scroll.  I have been researching this for a really long time and trying a bunch of stuff.  But nothing worked quite right for what I need.

Heres the [site](http://www.brainstormy.herokuapp.com)

What I need is a footer that stays at the bottom, even when the window shrinks and the panels overflow that when I scroll down, the footer doesn't go up.  But I also need to have liquid heights.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out without using bootstrap or JQuery.

I need this:

```
body > #main { 
position: fixed; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
overflow: auto;
}

footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

as well as adding absolute positioning to footer elements to prevent them from getting pushed down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use twitter bootstrap. Have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/mokagio/1918937).

Answer (score 0):

Your options are essentially to use a framework(twitter-bootstrap and zurb-foundation are both good options) or to write your own javascript/jquery to move the footer as you scroll. Check out this page: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/ You could do something like this:

```
$('#body').scroll(function(){
   $('#body').append('#your_footer');
});
```

Obviously, this is borderline pseudo-code but it might be a good jumping off point if you don't want to load an entire css framework just to scroll a footer.